# Passing a function with a parameter to hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, svg, hover, jquery-animate

I am new to jQuery and I feel like I missing something very obvious and fundamental but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

In any case I had a bit of code that would animate the stroke width to a wider amount when the object was hovered over and it worked:

```
$(function() {
    $("#wheel1").hover(grow1, shrink1);
});

function grow1(evt) {
    $("#wheel1").animate({'stroke-width':'100'},300);
    $("#circle1container").css({'display':'block'});
    $("#circle1container").animate({'opacity':'1'},300);
}

function shrink1(evt) {
    $("#wheel1").animate({'stroke-width':'55'},300);
    $("#circle1container").animate({'opacity':'0'},300);
}
```

But I had 10 other objects that I also wanted to do this for, so rather than copying and pasting this 9 more times and changing the number 9 times, I tried to consolidate it and this did not work:

```
$(function() {
$("#wheel1").hover(grow("1"), shrink("1"));
$("#wheel2").hover(grow("2"), shrink("2"));
$("#wheel3").hover(grow("3"), shrink("3"));
$("#wheel4").hover(grow("4"), shrink("4"));
$("#wheel5").hover(grow("5"), shrink("5"));
$("#wheel6").hover(grow("6"), shrink("6"));
$("#wheel7").hover(grow("7"), shrink("7"));
$("#wheel8").hover(grow("8"), shrink("8"));
$("#wheel9").hover(grow("9"), shrink("9"));
$("#wheel10").hover(grow("10"), shrink("10"));

function grow(number) {
var name = "#wheel" + number;
$("#wheel" + number).animate({'stroke-width':'100'},300);
$("#circle" + number + "container").css({'display':'block'});
$("#circle" + number + "container").animate({'opacity':'1'},300);
}

function shrink(number) {
$("#wheel" + number).animate({'stroke-width':'55'},300);
$("#circle" + number + "container").animate({'opacity':'0'},300);
}

});
```

Probably still not the most efficient way, but a bit less lengthy and easier to change I thought. I'm just not sure what the deal is here. Any help welcome, thank you!

http://jsfiddle.net/F4Yjj/5/ This shows the object I am trying to animate on hover with the hover working for the green shape (the first bit of code in this message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting wheels using IDs, which must be unique, give each wheel a class of "wheel" so that you can select all of them at once:

```
<path id="wheel10" class="wheel" .... />
<path id="wheel9" class="wheel" ... />
etc.
```

Then, you can select all "wheels" using jQuery and refer to the one that's hovered using `$(this)` in your functions:

```
$(function() {
    $("path.wheel").hover(grow1, shrink1);
});

function grow1() {
    $(this).animate({'stroke-width':'100'},300);
}

function shrink1() {
    $(this).animate({'stroke-width':'55'},300);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F4Yjj/1/

EDIT: Using this method, you don't need "evt" in your functions.
http://jsfiddle.net/F4Yjj/3/

EDIT: To also display another element. Given that you have a different physical element for each wheel (as shown in your updated HTML), you can determine the ID of the hovered wheel and select the other element by its ID:

```
function grow1() {
    var id=$(this).prop('id').split('_');
    $(this).animate({'stroke-width':'100'},300);
    $("#circlecontainer_"+id[1]).fadeIn(300);
}

function shrink1() {
    var id=$(this).prop('id').split('_');
    $(this).animate({'stroke-width':'55'},300);
    $("#circlecontainer_"+id[1]).fadeOut(100);
}
```

This fiddle has circles for wheel1 and wheel2: http://jsfiddle.net/F4Yjj/7/

You could also condense this by using one center circle for all wheels. Upon hover, update the circle's text with the proper percentages, colors, etc.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense thank you! Although if I wanted to make a different object appear in the middle of the ring for each part, would this still be the method to go about this?

Comment: That depends on what you want to appear. Would it be like a label or something that is always displayed in the same place but the text content changes?

Comment: I edited the jsfiddle & my post to sort of illustrate what I was thinking. Should be live now.

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion, given your updated code.

Comment: Ah, I finally got it! Thanks so much, perhaps the next time I will go about it in a better manner to avoid loading new objects every time. But much appreciated! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

use a class instead of an ID by using a class selector your hover will be applied to all applicable classes. As a side note i wouldn't use hover as i believe it's been deprecated in jquery 1.9.1 or 2 Instead you could just use mousein and mouseout.

something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('mousein','.wheel',function(){
    $(this).animate({'stroke-width':'100'},300);
  });

  $('body').on('mouseout','.wheel',function(){
    $(this).animate({'stroke-width':'55'},300);
  });
});
```

then just make sure all your wheels with id have an additional class of .wheel

Comment: Interesting. Where did you see that `hover` is depreciated?

Comment: `.hover()` is not deprecated. However, the `"hover"` pseudo-event, which is an entirely different thing, is: http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes. Also see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11731

Comment: ah i guess i must have seen the pseudo-event my bad